# YouTube videos on Khan Academy do not play

Tags: youtube

I just finished installing Ubuntu. YouTube videos do not play. I'd like to be able to view Khan Academy videos, which I think are YouTube videos.

When I go to KA, the video area is black until I put my cursor there. Then it goes white.

According to the Software Center, the Adobe Flash player is installed.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! It would be helpful if you provided us some more information about your setup. For example, what web browser are you using, have you tried restarting your browser after installing Flash, what's the name and version of the Flash package you have installed (e.g. `flashplugin-installer 11.2.202.238ubuntu0.12.04.1`), etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to enable HTML5 support for YouTube to avoid flash altogether.

Point your browser to

> http://www.youtube.com/html5

and enable HTML5 there. Reload the page from the Khan Academy and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

I use KA! Just use the HTML5 player; [youtube.com/html5](http://www.youtube.com/html5)

Answer (score 1):

If you for some reason don't want to enable HTML5 which I do recommend you can also install Google Chrome which has its own flash player built into the browser separate from the one installed through the software center.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with ZDF mediathek (german) [Click](http://www.zdf.de/ZDFmediathek/kanaluebersicht/aktuellste/760014?bc=sts;stt)
There is an explanation above:
Mediathek uses Flash version 10.1.0. Please install Flash version 10.1.0

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Can you expand this answer so it explains *how* to install Flash 10.10?